# Mouse freezes on login

Tags: 16.04, login, mouse, inspiron

My touchpad and mouse buttons freeze whenever I login, making my system basically unusable. My keyboard still works fine, I can access terminal, etc. If I logout with Ctrl+Alt+Del, my mouse cursor comes back and works fine, but as soon as I log back in it freezes again. Sometimes it just freezes, other times it also becomes invisible.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell Inspiron. This problem did not occur when I updated or anything, the mouse cursor just stopped moving while I was browsing the internet and has been dysfunctional ever since. If I use the wireless mouse it responds, but not with the touchpad.

Rebooting does not help, neither did `sudo modprobe -r psmouse; sudo modprobe psmouse`

Comment: Your touchpad is defective. Itśhardware, nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: If the touchpad is defective, how come it works on the login screen?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu1  *;-)** Does it work in the guest session???

Comment: Good question! I just checked and it actually does work in the guest session!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `~/.config/dconf/user` file. I had the same problem, and this is what solved it.

I haven't yet figured out which specific setting caused the problem, but you can use the information in this answer to dump the settings and reload them selectively: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199836/how-can-i-view-the-content-of-a-backup-of-the-dconf-database-file

Answer (score 0):

I went into Guest and it works. When I logged back into my account it worked again. Never had the problem before, I hope it doesn't reoccur. Most of the technical advice I see here is a bit much.